# android listview 3d transform like Clear app on ios

Tags: android, ios

I looking for a way to achieve similar effect (3d transform) like Clear app on IOS for android. How I should start?

Answer (score 0):

Are you talking about the kind of effect near 18 second mark of [this video?](http://www.realmacsoftware.com/clear/) I'm kind of a control freak, so I would likely just use canvas and animate/draw two trapezoids that grow from 0 height and bright color, to 1/2 height and dim color, then on the second phase would grow from current state to full height and bright color.

It would be a bit of a pain, because you would have to create enough space for the, and track the animations, but it would give you the desired result.